# Python GUI making a back button

Tags: python

```
class dashboard(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(dashboard, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.main_menu()

    def main_menu(self):
        for button in self.student_page_buttons: 
            button.grid_forget()
        #student dashboard button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Student",
                       command=self.student, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #teacher dashboard button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Teacher",
                       command=self.teacher, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #exit button
        bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
               command=self.exit, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()

        self.main_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3  # Save button widgets.

    def student(self):
        for button in self.main_page_buttons:  # Hide the main page Buttons.
            button.grid_forget()

        #view highscores button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Highscores",
                       command=self.view_scores, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #print score button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Save Score",
                       command=self.save_score, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #back button
        bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Back",
               command=self.main_menu, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()

        self.student_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3  # Save button widgets.
```

Been trying to make a back button for a while now and can't figure out why this back button isn't working, if anyone has some suggestions or useful links that would be great. I basically want to be able to access the student section along with going back to the main menu with just the main menu buttons and not both students and main menu combined.

Comment: What happens when you click the back button now?

Comment: No buttons appear whatsoever